# How does this Lambda Expression work?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm familiar with simple lambda expressions. However I have this lambda expression in a book.

```
dd_pair = defaultdict(lambda: [0,0])
dd_pair[2][1] = 1    #now dd_pair contains {2: [0,1]}
```

I didn't declare any input variables, which is not how I learned Lambdas.

The previous example from the book has

```
dd_dict = defaultdict(dict)
dd_dict["Joel"]["City"] = "Seattle"
#this produces {"Joel" : { "City": "Seattle"}}
```

This makes sense, The Key is `Joel`, the nested Key is `City`, and the value is `Seattle`.

My two part question is, how does a lambda work with no input variables? and should I assume that the `dd_pair[2][1]` is to create a key `2` and at index `1` of the list set the value `=1`?

Comment: `lambda`, like a regular function definition, can have no input parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda: [0, 0]` is exactly the same as:

```
def zero_pair():
    return [0, 0]
```

that is, it is a function that takes no arguments and returns a `len` 2 array with the two entries set to 0.  `defaultdict` takes a callable that takes no arguments and returns the value for a missing key so your second example (`dd_pair = defaultdict(lambda: [0,0])`) is the same as:

```
dd_pair = defaultdict(zero_pair)
```

Now, a dictionary in Python can take any value for its key (as long as they are [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)).

```
{0: 'integer', '0': 'string'}[0]  # 'integer'
```

So when we index into `dd_pair` with a two, since the dictionary doesn't have any key at `2` our lambda (which is equivalent to `zero_pair`) is called and returns a list with two zeros in it.  We then set the second element in that list to 1, mutating the list in place.

So yes, you're pretty much spot on when you say:

> should I assume that the `dd_pair[2][1]` is to create a key 2 and at index 1 of the list set the value = 1